# Internal role shown in wso2is but not shown in wso2am

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process, wso2-identity-server

We have wso2am-2.1.0, wso2bps-3.6.0, wso2is-km-5.3.0 and mysql. We set up humanTasks for the user signUp process in the store. After approving in userdb (mysql), an entry about the addition of the role internal / subscriber to the user appears and it is displayed in IS, but this role is not added to APIM. The same happens if we manually add a role to IS. Any ideas for solving this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it mean you are not able to access APIM using those users/roles ? Have you verified them on /carbon UI ? Also make sure that each user has the permission to access store/publisher.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! We have already solved this problem, the reason was in the configuration error, APIM looked into the internal database